# Angular: Equivalent of ng:class for custom attributes?

Tags: angularjs

In Angular, imagine a case like:

```
<a href="foo" data-bubble="{{unread_badge_counts.bcal}}">bCal</a>
```

Where I don't want the data-bubble attribute to appear in the DOM at all if unread_badge_counts.bcal = 0.

I was expecting to find a directive similar to ng:class, which would let me stick a little conditional in there. But I'm not seeing anything about this in the docs. Suggestions?

Comment: have you tried it? e.g. `unread_badge_counts.bcal ? "unread_badge_counts.bcal" : ""` or for that matter `unread_badge_counts.bcal || ""`

Comment: This does not work, unfortunately. Now trying the directive approach below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a simple directive just for this purpose:

```
app.directive('bubble', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // Whatever the data-bubble attr is set to will
        // be the expression we watch.
        var expr = attrs.bubble;

        scope.$watch(expr, function(val) {
            if (val > 0) {
                element.attr('data-bubble', val);
            } else {
                element.removeAttr('data-bubble');
            }
        });

    };
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8tGK/). The "Inspect me" will be gray if there's a `data-bubble` attribute on it, no background otherwise.

Comment: Thanks much satchmorun. I ended up solving this another way, but really appreciate the working code!

Comment: @shacker could you please post your solution as well?